# Docker Build Error : The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install –y apache2' returned a non-zero code: 100

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install –y apache2 
RUN apt-get install –y apache2-utils 
RUN apt-get clean 
EXPOSE 80
CMD [“apache2ctl”, “-D”, “FOREGROUND”]
```

when i am running this command `docker build –t=”mywebserver” .` I am getting below provided error in console

```
E: Unable to locate package –y
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install –y apache2' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Comment: You should read this article https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/, especially block about apt-get inside containers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure how, but I think you're using an en dash instead of a hyphen in front of your y.

You want `-y` rather than `–y`

If you look closely there's a subtle difference.

Comment: I think the formatting is being lost with the copy. If you look at the `"` it's a `“`.

Comment: Indeed, but the hyphens in ```apt-get``` are correct. A copy and paste into my local environment of the OP's ```–y``` gives me the same error. I would suggest it's definintely worth trying. If the OP copied and pasted the code, they may accidentally have introduced this error.

Comment: Hi , ya that was the issue...but now i am getting different error i.e,
Invalid containerPort: CMD

Comment: it's definitely the copy / paste from the docker docs...

Comment: In my case both hyphen and apostrophe both need correcting. Thanks to the eagle eyed!

Answer (score 1):

The `Dockerfile` looks fine so could be something to do with a proxy/firewall.

I would try the following:

```
FROM ubuntu 
RUN apt-get update
```

Run with `docker build --no-cache -t mywebserver` and see if it performs the update without issues. If not then I would suggest looking at setting `http/https` proxy with `ENV` inside the dockerfile.